# Docker Images Command Not Returning All Images

Tags: windows, docker

I am building a local app using docker, build was successful, when I use `docker images ls` command it is not returning any images, however when I use the command `docker images` without the `ls` I can see all images on my machine. I tried adding the filter `--all` when using `docker images ls` but still couldn't see my images.

I am using Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b and windows 10 OS, my docker machine is set up to use Linux VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `docker images ls` is mispelling

`docker images` command [doesn't have](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#options) `ls` subcommand.

As you can see, `docker images` works well without `ls`

The meaning of your case interpreted by `docker` like this:

- get images with `docker images`
- optionally get `--all` images
- and then show **only** images with `ls` name

### `docker image` vs `images`

There is more general command `docker image` (without `s`).

And [`docker image`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image/) command **does** have [`ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/) subcommand.